# Add attribuites to JSX.Element after declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

If I have an element in let's say a dictionary like this:

```js
let item = {
    element: <myElement/>,
    color: "#0e76a8"
}
```

Can I in render() add style attribute to the item.element ?

I imagined something like this would work just fine but it doesn't

```
return (
        <div>
            {<item.element style={{ color: "item.color" }/>}
        </div>
    );
```

Is there a way in JSX or React to achieve what I want?

Note: My goal isn't being able to change item.color. It's just I need abstraction because in my code I'll have list of different `item` variable and render each one with the desired attributes, I don't want to hardcode it in JSX to be easier to find in case of any future changes.

Comment: `"item.color"` is a string, I presume you want `item.color`

Comment: You can use style object and change styles dinamicaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know, placing `<` and `>` around a function reference in JSX will *apply* that functional component.

You don't want to apply your component when defining your `item` object, you only want to keep a reference to it for application later:

```
let item = {
    element: myElement,
    color: "#0e76a8"
}
```

Also, as [noted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60528090/add-attribuites-to-jsx-element-after-declaration#comment107080069_60528090), you're setting the `color` CSS style to the string `"item.color"`, whereas we can safely assume you mean `color: item.color`

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna do that:

```
return (
        <div>
            {<item.element style={{ color: item.color }/>}
        </div>
    );
```